# Convert drawing.bitmap to windows.controls.image

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, type-conversion

I am reading data from a smartcard. 
This data contains a picture as well.
Code to get the picture in a class ReadData:

```
public Bitmap GetPhotoFile()
    {
        byte[] photoFile = GetFile("photo_file");
        Bitmap photo = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(photoFile));
        return photo;
    }
```

Code in the xaml:

```
imgphoto = ReadData.GetPhotoFile();
```

Error being generated:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'**

What is the best approach in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` from that file. `Bitmap` is WinForms, not WPF.

Instead, create a WPF `BitmapImage`

```
public ImageSource GetPhotoFile()
{
    var photoFile = GetFile("photo_file");
    var photo = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(photoFile))
    {
        photo.BeginInit();
        photo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        photo.StreamSource = stream;  
        photo.EndInit();
    }

    return photo;
}
```

Then assign the returned `ImageSource` to the `Source` property of the Image control:

```
imgphoto.Source = ReadData.GetPhotoFile();
```